# PowerBI Dax - Calculated column to bring value based on date with conditions

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, powerbi, dax, formula

my goal is to a have calculated column that indicates which upcoming order will be used to fill the stock shortage. Below picture shows how the table currently  and what I have achieved. I am able to bring the next upcoming order based on the reschedule date but I am not able to bring the orders in right order. I have simplified the view into Excel but I have data in Powerbi and using Dax.

[image]

Currently I am using below formula but I am not able to edit that it would when spot when to change to next order. Formula should realize that reschedule date is lower than date when shortage is happening but it should not be higher than next order's reschedule date.

```
Upcoming orders  = 

IF([Indicator] = "Late" && [Change] = "-",

CALCULATE (
MAX ( 'Table1'[ID]),

FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Resch date] < [Date] && [Change] = "+" )

),BLANK())
```

Below would be my goal.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any tips and help.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Upcoming orders =
IF(
    [Indicator] = "Late" && [Change] = "-",
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table1'[ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Table1'),
            'Table1'[Resch date] < [Date] &&
            'Table1'[Resch date] > EARLIER('Table1'[Resch date]) &&
            'Table1'[Change] = "+"
        )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Here `EARLIER('Table1'[Resch date])` returns the 'Resch date' of the current row being evaluated in the outer loop.

It allows the inner FILTER function to compare each 'Resch date' against the current row's 'Resch date'.

[More Details on EARLIER function](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/how-to-use-the-earlier-function-in-power-bi-a-dax-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you @Alastair for you comment and a tip. This gave me a similar outcome as my current formula but I will take a look into EARLIER function if its something that could help with my problem! I think the issue still is that there needs to be a way when the formula realises that below or whenever the next order comes has a higher or equal reschdule date compared to date column.

Comment: This is quite difficult actually. It would be very easy in SQL:

```SQL
SELECT
 table1.*,
 MAX(table2.ID)
FROM
 material_changes AS table1
LEFT JOIN
 material_changes AS table2 ON (table2."reschedule_date" <= table1."date" AND table1.indicator = 'shortage')
GROUP BY
    table1.material_number, table1.date, table1.change, table1.id, table1.qty_change, table1.stock, table1.indicator, table1.reschedule_date
ORDER BY
    table1.date;
```

But much harder with DAX

Can you perform the operation before getting the data inside PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I have found a fully working solution for you, though it does require a bit of duplication due to PowerBI's limitations.

Firstly, duplicate the table you are referencing. It doesn't need to be a full duplication but we need `ID` and `Reschedule Date`

[image: Duplicate Table]

We then go back to the original table and add this new column:

```
Solution_Column = 
VAR CurrentDate = Table1[date]
VAR CurrentIndicator = Table1[indicator]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Table2[ID]),
    FILTER(
        Table2,
        Table2[reschedule date] <= CurrentDate && CurrentIndicator = "shortage"
    )
)
```

For each row it looks up the `Date` and `Indicator` to check if it's a *shortage* row or not. If it is then it looks up the new table we created and pulls the highest *reschedule date* that is earlier than the *shortage* rows date

[image: Solution]

And there we go!